# Keras: reshape to connect lstm and conv

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

This question exists as a [github issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4172) , too.
I would like to build a neural network in Keras which contains both 2D convolutions and an LSTM layer.

The network should classify MNIST.
The training data in MNIST are 60000 grey-scale images of handwritten digits from 0 to 9. Each image is 28x28 pixels.

I've splitted the images into four parts (left/right, up/down) and rearranged them in four orders to get sequences for the LSTM.

```
|     |      |1 | 2|
|image|  ->  -------   -> 4 sequences: |1|2|3|4|,  |4|3|2|1|, |1|3|2|4|, |4|2|3|1|
|     |      |3 | 4|
```

One of the small sub-images has the dimension 14 x 14. The four sequences are stacked together along the width (shouldn't matter whether width or height).

This creates a vector with the shape [60000, 4, 1, 56, 14] where:

- 60000 is the number of samples
- 4 is the number of elements in a sequence (# of timesteps)
- 1 is the depth of colors (greyscale)
- 56 and 14 are width and height

Now this should be given to a Keras model.
The problem is to change the input dimensions between the CNN and the LSTM.
I searched online and found this question: [Python keras how to change the size of input after convolution layer into lstm layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254138/python-keras-how-to-change-the-size-of-input-after-convolution-layer-into-lstm-l)

The solution seems to be a Reshape layer which flattens the image but retains the timesteps (as opposed to a Flatten layer which would collapse everything but the batch_size).

Here's my code so far:

```
nb_filters=32
kernel_size=(3,3)
pool_size=(2,2)
nb_classes=10
batch_size=64

model=Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
    border_mode="valid", input_shape=[1,56,14]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))


model.add(Reshape((56*14,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(5))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

This code creates an error message:

> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Apparently the input to the Reshape layer is incorrect. As an alternative, I tried to pass the timesteps to the Reshape layer, too:

```
model.add(Reshape((4,56*14)))
```

This doesn't feel right and in any case, the error stays the same.

Am I doing this the right way ?
Is a Reshape layer the proper tool to connect CNN and LSTM ?

There are rather complex approaches to this problem. 
Such as this:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/1456
A TimeDistributed Layer which seems to hide the timestep dimension from following layers.

Or this: https://github.com/anayebi/keras-extra
A set of special layers for combining CNNs and LSTMs.

Why are there so complicated (at least they seem complicated to me) solutions, if a simple Reshape does the trick ?

**UPDATE**:

Embarrassingly, I forgot that the dimensions will be changed by the pooling and (for lack of padding) the convolutions, too.
[kgrm](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4172#issuecomment-255761223) advised me to use `model.summary()` to check the dimensions.

The output of the layer before the Reshape layer is `(None, 32, 26, 5)`,
I changed the reshape to: `model.add(Reshape((32*26*5,)))`.

Now the ValueError is gone, instead the LSTM complains:

> Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

It seems like I need to pass the timestep dimension through the entire network. How can I do that ? If I add it to the input_shape of the Convolution, it complains, too: `Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], border_mode="valid", input_shape=[4, 1, 56,14])`

> Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer convolution2d_44: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Comment: You can simply adopt a reshape operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789979/10375049

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Convolution2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d) definition your input must be 4-dimensional with dimensions `(samples, channels, rows, cols)`. This is the direct reason why are you getting an error.

To resolve that you must use [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) wrapper. This allows you to use static (not recurrent) layers across the time.