# How to stack Convolutional Layer and LSTM using Tensorflow2.0 alpha?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement a neural network for an NLP task with a convolutional layer followed up by an LSTM layer. I am currently experimenting with the new Tensorflow 2.0 to do this. However, when building the model, I've encountered an error that I could not understand.

```
# Input shape of training and validation set
(1000, 1, 512), (500, 1, 512)
```

**The model**

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 512)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 1, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D((2)))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation="tanh"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))
```

**The error**

```
InvalidArgumentError: Tried to stack elements of an empty list with non-fully-defined element_shape: [?,64]
 [[{{node unified_lstm_16/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_26641]
```

At first, I tried to check if there are any issues regarding implementing a `Conv1D` layer with an `LSTM` layer. I found [this post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/129), that suggested so that I reshaped the layer between the convolutional layer and lstm layer. But that still did not work and I got a different error instead. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431081/how-to-connect-convlolutional-layer-with-lstm-in-tensorflow-keras) seems similar but it does not use Tensorflow 2.0 and not answer so far. I also found this post that has the same intention of stacking a convolutional and lstm layers. But it uses `Conv2D` instead of `Conv1D`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254138/python-keras-how-to-change-the-size-of-input-after-convolution-layer-into-lstm-l) also suggests to use reshaped the output of the convolutional layer with a built-in layer called `Reshape`. Yet, I still got the same error.

I also tried to specify the `input_shape` in the LSTM layer.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 512)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 1, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D((2)))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation="tanh", input_shape=(None, 64)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))
```

And I still got the same error in the end.

I am not sure if I understand how to stack the 1-dimensional convolutional layer and lstm layer. I know that TF2.0 is still an Alpha, but did can someone point out what I was missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you print `model.summary` in the first case, would you get [None, None, 512] in input shape?

Comment: Maybe it is a dimensionnality issue. As @Sharky suggested, you can add the `model.summary` into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is a dimensionality issue. Your feature is of shape `[..., 1, 512]`; therefore, `MaxPooling1D` `pooling_size` 2 is bigger than 1 causing the issue.

Adding `padding="same"` will solve the issue.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, 512)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 1, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same"))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation="tanh"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))
```

Comment: Yep! That solved it, thank you very much! Any reason why padding solves it?

Comment: Great to see that it helped :). See my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

**padding="same"** should solve your issue.

Change below line:

`model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2, padding="same"))`

Comment: what's the difference between your answer and mine ?